# Valid/convincing proof that $\ \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n\ $ exists $\ \implies \lim_{i\to\infty}\left( \sum_{n=i}^{n=\infty} a_n \right) = 0\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Is this a valid or convincing proof that $\ \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n\ $ exists $\ \implies \lim_{i\to\infty}\left( \sum_{n=i}^{n=\infty} a_n \right) = 0\ ?$

For any $\ i\in\mathbb{N},$

$$ \sum_{n=i}^{n=\infty} a_n\ =\ \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n\ -\ \sum_{n=1}^{n=i-1} a_n. $$

Letting $\ i\to\infty\ $ gives the result.

I think this proof lacks rigour $(\varepsilon-n\ $ definition of limits), but it is still convincing to me.

Comment: It’s good for intuition but as you say, it lacks proper rigor. You can simplify the notation and argument slightly by writing the partial sums as $s_N$ and the entire sum as $s$. Then you just need to consider $|s-s_N|$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to distribute limits over sums (provided that the limit of your summands exist), then yes. As you said just take the limit of both sides as $i \rightarrow \infty$. There is no need for an $\varepsilon - n$ argument since by assumption $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n$ exists and the distribution of limits is justified.

You might want to redefine $\sum_{n=i}^{n=\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{n=i-1} a_n$ for $i=1$ since these are undefined as it stands. But of course, this doesn't affect your limit.